# Stanford NLP + Train for new currency like Rupee

Tags: stanford-nlp

[The online NER demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process) does a good job with currencies like $ and terms like million. For example: *BSES has invested over $ 7200 million on upgrading and augmenting the infrastructure.* The same fares poorly for terms used in India: *BSES has invested over Rs 7200 crores on upgrading and augmenting the infrastructure.*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing might be to use a rule-based approach.

Here is an example rule I put into currency-rules.txt

```
Rs [0-9]+ crores        MONEY   MISC    1
```

Here is the command I ran on your example sentence:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -regexner.mapping currency-rules.txt -file sample-sentence.txt -outputFormat text
```

It was able to correctly identify the phrase "Rs 7200 crores" as MONEY.

Also if you want to handle any currency symbols and having them normalized, you might want to look at this class:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/QuantifiableEntityNormalizer.java

If you have any suggestions for adding Indian currency I can add them to this class.